# Architectural Feedback

Tags: architecture, n-tier-architecture, servicebus

I am part of a large organization which has many different departments. Let's call them A,B, and C.
Each Department has its own system but some things are shared depending on the system. There is a reporting department which needs to see an aggregate of all the data from the different department systems.

We started out with each department having their own SQL Database and api's on top of it as well as a front end single page app. We added a Central Database to keep track of things such as Users, Phones, Addresses, EmailAddresses which are shared between systems.

As we are growing one of our biggest pain points is to keep everything in sync. For instance we had that one of the systems deleted a user from the central table or merged them together (which is a possibility) and thereby affected the other systems since there internal person referenced the central person which was deleted. One of our other systems decided they dont want to be affected by inter system changes and any deletes of phone numbers for example which are stored centrally shouldnt affect them.

i am trying to figure out the best way to handle this scenario. I was thinking along the lines of a pub sub scenario in which each system internally had its own set of lets say Phones,Addresses,EmailAddresses and when they make a change its published through rabbitMQ. The other systems can subscribe to them if they want and handle the changes accordingly.

This all sounds good but how do we track users across systems for reporting. We want to use a UserID which is consistent across systems. Let's say a User comes into System A and he retreives a global ID from some central place and a month later the same user comes into System B. Given we have their email address so System B could know their related but how does it find this information out, does it query a central system or does it kind of send out a message such as "Who has this User in their system" and wait for an answer from the any given system.

Anyways i would appreciate any feedback on the matter.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you read a couple of books on this or scan the web:

- Domain Driven Design
- Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture
- CQRS

You are on the right track w.r.t. using an event-driven architecture (service bus).